# Jenkins aws device farm pugin unable to find artifact / apk

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, jenkins, glob, aws-device-farm

I am using jenkins to do the build for a Android project which works fine but uploading the apk to device farm results in a IOException as the plugin can't find the file.

Build Log

```
[AWSDeviceFarm] Using Project 'Android SDK2'
[AWSDeviceFarm] Using DevicePool 'Test Devices'
[AWSDeviceFarm] Using App '/AndroidSDK/PlayerSDK/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/PlayerSDK-debug-androidTest.apk'
[AWSDeviceFarm] Unable to find artifact java.io.IOException: Expecting Ant GLOB pattern, but saw '/AndroidSDK/PlayerSDK/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/PlayerSDK-debug-androidTest.apk'. See http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html for syntax
Build step 'Run Tests on AWS Device Farm' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have tried changing application path to

> **/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/PlayerSDK-debug-androidTest.apk
>   and
>
> **/PlayerSDK-debug-androidTest.apk

but this leads to "No artificats found at this location" error.  Any ideas?

Comment: Hi there, 

The error says that it can find the file but it appears to be expecting Ant GLOB pattern. So the path you had originally is correct. 

Are we sure that the plugin as access to all the files and that the type of test we&#39;re selecting is instrumentation?

Comment: @jmp The plugin should have access to the file. If it can find the file, it should be able to read it. And yes I have selected instrumentation tests. This is a library project so in application I can only provide PlayerSDK-debug-androidTest.apk which is the same file I provide in Instrumentation tests as well. This appears to work well on amazon web UI.

Comment: If the jenkins installation is hosted on an ec2 instance or something similar it might be a permissions issue with the service. Could you try using the aws cli to upload the file? Here are the commands to do that: 

//get the project arn
aws devicefarm list-projects --region us--west-2

 aws devicefarm create-upload –project-arn <yourProjectArn> –name PlayerSDK-debug-androidTest.apk –type INSTRUMENTATION_TEST_PACKAGE  --region us-west-2

//upload the file to the s3 url returned

curl -T /relative/path/to/apk "s3PresignedUrl"